How to recognize within application that i am within an testcafe e2e test
We are within a big project migration.
Old pages written in php and tested with testcafe.
New pages written with Nuxt and tested with playwright.
I need to know on nuxt pages if i am running an e2e test with testcafe. Dependant on the result i need to guide the user to old version of checkout instead of new version when clicking on a button.
Within the documentation or by googling around i cannot find any way to know within my application if i am currently within the testcafe tests.
Can anyone help?
I tried setting an env var for testcafe, but its not recognized by the nuxt application.
I tried working with a window object, like window._isTestcafe  but also this does not work.
I found this thread: How can my application code know whether the app is being tested with testcafe?
and tried the window['%hammerhead%'] which is also not working.
I know in Cypress there is the possibility to access window.Cypress within your application and access env vars from cypress. Is there maybe any equivalent for testcafe?

The answer is that window?.['%hammerhead%'] works. But i need to wait until onMounted in nuxt, because before on mounted the value ist not set.
